# How to jump back to root in NavigationStack

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have three views: a List, Details view and Edit view, that work nicely together. I show the List, navigate to one item in the list and from there, can open it to Edit. But when I’m in Edit, I want to be able to delete the item and then return to the List. But when I do this, I get back to Details, not List. I’ve tried different tutorials (setting the NavigationPath to nil etc) I’ve found online, but nothing seems to work.

I’ve removed all the different things I’ve tried and just left the basic flow that currently works fine. Any help is very much appreciated.

Here’s my code:

```
struct ThingsView: View {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext
    @Query(sort: [SortDescriptor(\Thing.name)]) private var things: [Thing]
    
    @State private var selectedThing: Thing?
    
    @State private var columnVisibility: NavigationSplitViewVisibility = .doubleColumn
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView(columnVisibility: $columnVisibility) {
            List(things, selection: $selectedThing) { thing in
                NavigationLink {
                    ThingView(thing: thing)
                } label: {
                    ThingRow(thing: thing)
                }
            }
            .listStyle(.plain)
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem {
                    NavigationLink {
                        EditView(thing: nil)
                    } label: {
                        Label("Add thing", systemImage: "plus")
                    }
            }
            .navigationTitle("My things")
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.large)
        } detail: {
            NavigationStack {
                if let selectedThing = selectedThing {
                    ThingView(thing: selectedThing)
                        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.large)
                } else {
                    Text("Please select a thing from the list of add a new one.")
                        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.large)
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationSplitViewStyle(.balanced)
    }
}
```

```
struct ThingView: View {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext

    var thing: Thing
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            // Some VStacks and HStacks
        }
        .navigationTitle(thing.fullName())
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.large)
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                NavigationLink {
                    EditView(thing: thing)
                } label: {
                    Label("Edit", systemImage: "square.and.pencil")
                }
                .frame(width: 16, height: 16)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
struct EditView: View {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext
    @Environment(\.dismiss) private var dismiss
    
    @State var thing: Thing?
    
    var body: some View {
        let textfieldPadding = EdgeInsets(top: 4, leading: 0, bottom: 4, trailing: 0)
        Form {
            if let thing = thing {
                VStack(alignment: .center) {
                    Button(role: .destructive) {
                        showConfirmation = true
                    } label: {
                        HStack {
                            Image(systemName: "trash")
                            Text("Delete")
                        }
                    }
                    .controlSize(.extraLarge)
                    .confirmationDialog("Are you sure?", isPresented: $showConfirmation, titleVisibility: .hidden) {
                        Button("Delete thing", role: .destructive, action: {
                            modelContext.delete(thing)
                            dismiss()
                        })
                    } message: {
                        Text("Deleting a thing will delete all data. It cannot be undone.")
                    }
                }
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.large)
        .navigationTitle(thing == nil ? "New thing" : "Edit thing")
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                Button("Save") {
                    saveThing()
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func saveThing() {
        do {
            try modelContext.save()
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        dismiss()
    }
}
```

Comment: are you sure you tried navigation path?  NavigationStack easily pops to root if you associate navaigationpath with it.  You can just do path.removelast(path.count) or reset the path like path = NavigationPath().

Comment: For inspiration: https://notificare.com/blog/2022/11/25/a-better-tabview-in-swiftui/

Comment: Your navigation link `Navigation(destination:label:` may cause troubles in Compact Mode. You may better use an initialiser with a `value` parameter, for example: `NavigationLink(_ title:String, value:Thing?)`. The value will be ignored in a `NavigationSplitView`, since you handle the _selected_ value in the `detail` closure. The documentation explicitly makes notes about this. So, this seems to be "idiomatic".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your top-level navigation container is a `NavigationSplitView`. When a `Thing` is selected, you use a nested `NavigationStack` in the detail view to allow nested views below the detail. That's fine. However, when the selected `Thing` is deleted, I assume that what you really want to do is pop back to the view of the `NavigationSplitView` where there is no selection. This is why it doesn't help to use a `path` for the `NavigationStack`, because you actually want to pop back to before there was any selection.

I was able to get it working with these changes:

- The list items in the top-level `sidebar` view of the `NavigationSplitView` need to be simple labels, not `NavigationLink`.
- When a `Thing` is deleted, the state variable `selectedThing` needs to be reset. This then causes the detail view to be replaced. It is not even necessary to call `dismiss()` from the detail view.
- One way to allow `selectedThing` to be reset easily from a nested context would be to move it into your model. Then it can be reset automatically when `delete` is called. Alternatively, you can pass a `Binding` to the child views.

Here is an updated version of your example which shows it working (with gaps improvised). It uses the approach of having `selectedThing` held by the model:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {

    @StateObject private var modelContext = ModelContext()

    var body: some View {
        ThingsView()
            .environmentObject(modelContext)
    }
}

class ModelContext: ObservableObject {
    @Published private var allThings: [Thing]
    @Published var selectedThing: Thing?

    init() {
        self.allThings = [Thing(name: "First"), Thing(name: "Second"), Thing(name: "Third")]
    }

    var things: [Thing] {
        allThings
    }

    func delete(_ thing: Thing) {
        if let index = allThings.firstIndex(of: thing) {
            allThings.remove(at: index)
            selectedThing = nil
        }
    }
}

struct Thing: Identifiable, Hashable {
    let name: String

    var id: String {
        name
    }

    func fullName() -> String {
        name
    }
}

struct ThingsView: View {
//    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext
    @EnvironmentObject private var modelContext: ModelContext
//    @Query(sort: [SortDescriptor(\Thing.name)]) private var things: [Thing]
//    @State private var selectedThing: Thing?

    @State private var columnVisibility: NavigationSplitViewVisibility = .doubleColumn

    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView(columnVisibility: $columnVisibility) {
            List(modelContext.things, selection: $modelContext.selectedThing) { thing in
                Text(thing.fullName())
                    .tag(thing)
            }
            .listStyle(.plain)
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem {
                    NavigationLink {
                        EditView(thing: nil)
                    } label: {
                        Label("Add thing", systemImage: "plus")
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("My things")
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.large)
        } detail: {
            NavigationStack {
                if let selectedThing = modelContext.selectedThing {
                    ThingView(thing: selectedThing)
                        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.large)
                } else {
                    Text("Please select a thing from the list or add a new one.")
                        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.large)
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationSplitViewStyle(.balanced)
    }
}

struct ThingView: View {
//    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext

    var thing: Thing

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            // Some VStacks and HStacks
        }
        .navigationTitle(thing.fullName())
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.large)
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                NavigationLink {
                    EditView(thing: thing)
                } label: {
                    Label("Edit", systemImage: "square.and.pencil")
                }
                .frame(width: 16, height: 16)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct EditView: View {
//    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext
    @EnvironmentObject private var modelContext: ModelContext
    @Environment(\.dismiss) private var dismiss

    @State var thing: Thing?
    @State private var showConfirmation = false

    var body: some View {
//        let textfieldPadding = EdgeInsets(top: 4, leading: 0, bottom: 4, trailing: 0)
        Form {
            if let thing = thing {
                VStack(alignment: .center) {
                    Button(role: .destructive) {
                        showConfirmation = true
                    } label: {
                        HStack {
                            Image(systemName: "trash")
                            Text("Delete")
                        }
                    }
                    .controlSize(.extraLarge)
                    .confirmationDialog("Are you sure?", isPresented: $showConfirmation, titleVisibility: .hidden) {
                        Button("Delete thing", role: .destructive, action: {
                            modelContext.delete(thing)
//                            dismiss()
                        })
                    } message: {
                        Text("Deleting a thing will delete all data. It cannot be undone.")
                    }
                }
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.large)
        .navigationTitle(thing == nil ? "New thing" : "Edit thing")
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                Button("Save") {
                    saveThing()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private func saveThing() {
        print("save thing")
//        do {
//            try modelContext.save()
//        } catch {
//            print(error.localizedDescription)
//        }
        dismiss()
    }
}
```

[image: Animation]